# Formatting author names with orcid and affiliations in RMarkdown

Tags: latex, r-markdown, pandoc, author, orcid

I am unable to make the title page using RMarkdown the way I usually do using LaTeX.

Here is my current code in markdown:

```
---
title: 'Research on the use of mirrors on rooftops to focus on Starlink satellites to burn them down because they interfere with amateur astronomy'
author:
- Heinz Doof, University of Okomba, Lucario 52500, Wakanda.
- Phenias Krill, Barry University, Millet Department, Dublin DD 0562, Ireland.
- Ferb Mayo, University of Okomba, Lucario 52500, Wakanda.
- Pablo Macro, Barry University, Millet Department, Dublin DD 0562, Ireland.
date: "19 June 2023"
output:
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: yes
  word_document: default
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
---
```

And this is the corresponding output:

[image: Current]

I want to add the ORCiD links and group the affiliations using numberings. Something like this:

[image: Expected]

Answer (score 1):

For pdf output, to format author names with orcid link and affiliations, you may try the [`authblk`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/authblk) and [`orcidlink`](https://ctan.org/pkg/orcidlink) latex package.

Now to include the affiliations for each author, I have used the yaml keys `name`, `affil-id`, `id`, `affiliations`. These will act as interpolated variables as pandoc template. So copy the contents of [pandoc template for latex](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/blob/master/default.latex) into a file `default.tex` and then replace the line in the `default.tex` file [`\author{$for(author)$$author$$sep$ \and $endfor$}`](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/blob/master/default.latex#L466) with the following,

```
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{orcidlink}
\renewcommand\Affilfont{\small}

$for(author)$
\author$if(it.affil-id)$[$it.affil-id$]$endif${$it.name$}
$endfor$

$if(affiliations)$
$for(affiliations)$
\affil[$it.id$]{$it.name$}
$endfor$
$endif$
```

and then use this template in the rmarkdown file using `template` yaml key.

```yaml
---
title: 'Research on the use of mirrors on rooftops to focus on Starlink satellites to burn them down because they interfere with amateur astronomy'
author:
  - name: Heinz Doof \orcidlink{0000-0000-0000-0001}
    affil-id: 1,3
  - name: Phenias Krill \orcidlink{0000-0000-0000-0002}
    affil-id: 2
  - name: Ferb Mayo \orcidlink{0000-0000-0000-0003}
    affil-id: 1
  - name: Pablo Macro \orcidlink{0000-0000-0000-0004}
    affil-id: 1
affiliations: 
  - id: 1
    name: University of Okomba, Lucario 52500, Wakanda.
  - id: 2
    name: Barry University, Millet Department, Dublin DD 0562, Ireland.
  - id: 3
    name: University of Ubuntu, some address.
date: July 6, 2023
geometry:
- margin=1in
output:
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: yes
    template: default.tex
---
```

knitting the above rmarkdown file generates the following,

[image: authors names with affiliations and orcidlink]